# Host accepts ICMP but does not accept TCP/UDP

Tags: networking, tcp

I'm running Mininet with a custom topology and P4 on Ubuntu 20.04. The issue happens between two hosts (h1 and h11) that are connected through a switch. The following is the configuration of the hosts:

h1: IP 10.0.11.1, mac: 08:00:00:00:11:01. I have manually configured the arp with `arp -i h1-eth0 -s 10.0.11.11 08:00:00:00:11:00`

h11: IP 10.0.11.11, mac: 08:00:00:00:11:11. I have manually configured the arp with `arp -i h11-eth0 -s 10.0.11.1 08:00:00:00:11:00`

The switch runs the basic routing program in the P4-Tutorial, which will swap the mac address first and then put the correct destination mac in the packet. That is, the packet from h1 to h11 will be transformed to Ether(src=08:00:00:00:11:00, dst=08:00:00:00:11:11) / IP(src=10.0.11.1, dst=10.0.11.11). The packet from h11 to h1 will be transformed to Ether(src=08:00:00:00:11:00, dst=08:00:00:00:11:01) / IP(src=10.0.11.11, dst=10.0.11.1). So that's why I configure the arp in that way.

The ping commands (`h1 ping h11`, `h11 ping h1`) works fine, but when it comes to the TCP/UDP packets, h11 always fail to respond (or accept packets).

**[TCP]** When I try iperf (h1 -> h11), h11 will not respond to the SYN packet sent from h1, but on the interface of h11 I can capture the SYN packet, i.e. routing is correct. On the other way around (h11 -> h1), h11 will send the SYN packet. h1 will accept and respond with SYN+ACK. This SYN+ACK packet can be captured at the interface of h11, but neither will h11 respond with ACK nor will the iperf server program on h11 show anything.

**[UDP]** When I try `traceroute 10.0.11.1` on h11, it works fine (h1 returns UDP packets) and the results are as follows:

```
traceroute to 10.0.11.1 (10.0.11.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.0.11.1 (10.0.11.1)  3.292 ms  3.108 ms  3.173 ms
```

But when I try `traceroute 10.0.11.11` on h1, the result will be unreachable. Still, I can capture the UDP packet at h11's interface. It's just h11 never responds nor accepts at the application level.

There is no firewall set on both hosts. What could possibly go wrong with host h11 and how can I make it work? Thanks!

BTW, the iptable on both hosts are

```
root@machine# iptables -L -nv
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 5849  952K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5747 packets, 945K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

root@machine# iptables -t nat -L -nv
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

And I have the following results:

```
root@h11# ip neigh show
10.0.11.1 dev h11-eth0 lladdr 08:00:00:00:11:00 PERMANENT
root@h11# arp -i h11-eth0
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
10.0.11.1                ether   08:00:00:00:11:00   CM                    h11-eth0
```

```
root@h1# ip neigh show
10.0.11.11 dev h1-eth0 lladdr 08:00:00:00:11:00 PERMANENT
root@h1# arp -i h1-eth0
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
10.0.11.11               ether   08:00:00:00:11:00   CM                    h1-eth0
root@homer-vm4:/home/yunming/AppStreaming/load_balancer/LB7#
```

Further, I ran iperf (h11->h1) and this is what is captured on h11's interface:

```
root@h11# tcpdump -i h11-eth0 -e
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on h11-eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
16:57:07.202587 08:00:00:00:11:11 (oui Unknown) > 08:00:00:00:11:00 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.0.11.11.45938 > 10.0.11.1.5001: Flags [S], seq 3406863775, win 42340, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2081233344 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
16:57:07.203629 08:00:00:00:11:00 (oui Unknown) > 08:00:00:00:11:11 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.0.11.1.5001 > 10.0.11.11.45938: Flags [S.], seq 3060599012, ack 3406863776, win 43440, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2061897778 ecr 2081233344,nop,wscale 9], length 0
16:57:08.216329 08:00:00:00:11:11 (oui Unknown) > 08:00:00:00:11:00 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.0.11.11.45938 > 10.0.11.1.5001: Flags [S], seq 3406863775, win 42340, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2081234358 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
16:57:08.217393 08:00:00:00:11:00 (oui Unknown) > 08:00:00:00:11:11 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.0.11.1.5001 > 10.0.11.11.45938: Flags [S.], seq 3060599012, ack 3406863776, win 43440, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2061898791 ecr 2081233344,nop,wscale 9], length 0
16:57:08.217461 08:00:00:00:11:00 (oui Unknown) > 08:00:00:00:11:11 (oui Unknown), ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 10.0.11.1.5001 > 10.0.11.11.45938: Flags [S.], seq 3060599012, ack 3406863776, win 43440, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2061898792 ecr 2081233344,nop,wscale 9], length 0
```

Comment: Am I reading this correctly? Both IPs/hosts with the same mac address? That won't fly.

Comment: Just in case that is a small oversight on the question (probably the macs are different and it was mistyped), can you also provide the output of these commands on both hosts? `ip addr show; ip route show; iptables -L -nv; iptables -t nat -L -nv` (might need to run them with sudo).

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The switch will swap the mac address first and then put the correct destination mac in the packet. That is, the packet from h1 to h11 will be transformed to Ether(src=08:00:00:00:11:00, dst=08:00:00:00:11:11). The packet from h11 to h1 will be transformed to Ether(src=08:00:00:00:11:00, dst=08:00:00:00:11:01).

Comment: Actually, on top of all the commands I provided before, will also need `ip neigh show`.... also `arp -i the-interface-of-each-host`. And I bet you have been probing traffic moving around with `tshark` (or some other sniffer) on both hosts to see what IPs/mac-addresses are being used, right? Can you post that as well?

Comment: I just added the tcpdump results at h11's interface. Because h1 indeed responded and the packet was forwarded correctly (received by h11), I didn't put the tcpdump results at h1's interface

Comment: is the switch by any chance changing IP addresses? And why are there 2 synack packets?

Comment: I don't think it's changing IP addresses. The captured packets didn't show that. For the 2 synack packets I'm not sure, maybe because timeout so it tried again?